# ddump-rule-firings output when building Haskell program with Stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

How do I see the output of `-ddump-rule-firings` when building a program with stack?

I've added `-ddump-rule-firings` to `ghc-options` in my `.cabal` file and run `stack clean; stack build -v`. The rule firings (and any other output from ghc) are not included in the output of `stack`.

The normal ghc output doesn't seem to be logged anywhere in the `.stack-work` directory.

---

Other developers have [encountered similar issues](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/426), but the proposed change (adding a `--dump-logs` option) doesn't seem to be implemented:

```
>stack build --dump-logs
Invalid option `--dump-logs'

Usage: stack build [TARGET] [--dry-run] [--pedantic] [--fast]
                   [--ghc-options OPTION] [--flag PACKAGE:[-]FLAG]
                   ([--dependencies-only] | [--only-snapshot] |
                   [--only-dependencies]) ([--file-watch] | [--file-watch-poll])
                   [--exec CMD [ARGS]] [--only-configure] [--trace] [--profile]
                   [--[no-]library-profiling] [--[no-]executable-profiling]
                   [--[no-]haddock] [--haddock-arguments HADDOCK_ARGS]
                   [--[no-]open] [--[no-]haddock-deps] [--[no-]copy-bins]
                   [--[no-]prefetch] [--[no-]keep-going] [--[no-]force-dirty]
                   [--[no-]test] [--[no-]rerun-tests]
                   [--test-arguments TEST_ARGS] [--coverage] [--no-run-tests]
                   [--[no-]bench] [--benchmark-arguments BENCH_ARGS]
                   [--no-run-benchmarks] [--[no-]reconfigure]
                   [--[no-]cabal-verbose] [--[no-]split-objs] [--help]
  Build the package(s) in this directory/configuration
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the rules firing dumps in directories like the following

```
.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\build\src\Lib.dump-rule-firings
.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\build\iterate-strict-exe\iterate-strict-exe-tmp\app\Main.dump-rule-firings
```